# background color of the toast message in a flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the background color of the toast message in a flutter, the changes are not reflected.
My Flutter version is 2.8.1
in pubspec.yaml the  flutter toast is
fluttertoast: ^8.0.8

Help me with the solution.

```
 Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0
                  );
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try using like this:

```
 Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                      backgroundColor:  "#ff0000",
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0
                  );
```

Comment: it didn't work 

the error is 


(73:44: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                          backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                                           ^
)

Comment: I ran the exact same code as you've provided and I can see it working on iOS Simulator and on my Android Emulator plus real Android phone. Could you be more specific about which platform you are having this issue on? Is this not working for you on Windows/iOS/macOS/Linux/Web?

Comment: I use the Android Studio platform,  it is not working on  Windows-web @VandadNahavandipoor

Comment: Does this issue help? https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/340